# How To Give Authorization In Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I Have Login screen in android including username & password. if login successful then it goes to next activity(i.e. Save Action.Class).

My Question is that if i enter username & password of admin level it should Display All The Text boxes in Save Action Activity & Should Save it Successfully.

but if i enter username & password of employer level it should not display some text boxes & should not save it.

In Short i Want to give Role In my App. What I Have to do. Please Help me Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement your own ACL (Access Control List). There is no preexisting builtin architecture which would simplify your needs to my knowledge.

Comment: You mean to say i have to create table like username & role. after then i have to compare with it.                                     and have to check it out  current user is manager or employer??   after comparing i should give based on that...m i right?

Comment: OK. i can do that but question is how to disable text boxes when employer logins & manager Logins. i Mean what is the code behind disable & enable of text boxes. please help me.

Comment: This goes to basic Android/Java programming. It can't simply be answered here. You will need to learn ALL of the necessary components to make up your solution otherwise it wouldn't be called programming.